# How to create two different value in the same row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Below is the Data Set I am working on.

[image]

I am trying to create new column based on certain condition. Below is the code:-

```
SELECT
  *
,
CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('SAL%') THEN [Partner Name] 
ELSE ''
END AS [SAL Name],
    CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('SAL%') THEN [Partner Email Address] 
ELSE ''
END AS [SAL Email],
CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('CEO%') THEN [Partner Name] 
ELSE ''
END AS [CEO Name],
    CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('CEO%') THEN [Partner Email Address] 
ELSE ''
END AS [CEO Email],
    CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('VPS%') THEN [Partner Name] 
ELSE ''
END AS [VPS Name],
    CASE
WHEN [Partner Number] Like ('VPS%') THEN [Partner Email Address] 
ELSE ''
END AS [VPS Email]

     Into #Partner
  from (
         Select distinct  [Vendor Number],
[Purchasing Org],

[Partner Number],

[Partner Name]
, 
[Partner Email Address] from #Temp)k
```

But It is generating two different rows, if the set has both SAL and CAL.

It is possible to generate both of them in same row because when i am doing join , the data is getting explode .

Ideally both Sal Name and cal Name  in the same row.

Result

[image]

Comment: The way your query is set up makes it impossible to add duplicate values. So the duplicate values must allready be in your dataset. Furthermore is do not see the 'CAL' value you are referring to.

Comment: Focus on our SELECT DISTINCT statement at the bottom - it would appear to be producing multiple rows based on two columns in your select list that are unexpectedly different

Comment: Either use multiple joins to same table or pivot. And - if you need `distinct` keyword in your query, then usually something is wrong with your logic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more something you should do in the presentation layer.

But something like this should do it:

```
WITH cte_cat
as
(
    SELECT *,   CASE    WHEN partnerNumber like 'CEO%' THEN 'CEO' 
                        WHEN partnerNumber like 'SAL%' THEN 'SAL'
                        ELSE 'OTHER' END as Category

    FROM #yourtable
),
cte_rn
as
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY vendorNbr,purchasingOrg,Category ORDER BY Commodity) as RN
    FROM cte_cat
)

SELECT oth.vendorNbr,oth.purchasingOrg,oth.commodity,oth.partnerNumber,oth.PartnerName,oth.ParterEmail,CEO.partnerNumber,CEO.PartnerName,CEO.ParterEmail,SAL.partnerNumber,SAL.PartnerName,SAL.ParterEmail
FROM cte_rn oth
LEFT JOIN cte_rn CEO
    ON CEO.Category = 'CEO'
    AND oth.RN = CEO.rn
    AND oth.vendorNbr=CEO.vendorNbr
    AND oth.purchasingOrg = CEO.purchasingOrg
LEFT JOIN cte_rn SAL
    ON SAL.Category = 'SAL'
    AND oth.RN = SAL.rn
    AND oth.vendorNbr=SAL.vendorNbr
    AND oth.purchasingOrg = SAL.purchasingOrg

WHERE oth.Category ='OTHER';
```

Comment: its also creating a null row for each vendor if partner number is in both SAL and CEO. how to avoid that